# Loop through for all shortcuts in a given location and return the target path

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is it possible to loop through for all shortcuts (.lnk) in a given location and return the .TargetPath. If a shortcuts target matches a criteria an action can then be peformed on the shortcut?

To delete all shortcuts I would use the following:

```
Public Sub deleteAllShortcuts()
  Dim shortCutPath As String
  '   compName = Computer Name, recordDirShort = directory where the shortcut lnks are
  shortCutPath = compName & recordDirShort
  shortCutPath = shortCutPath & "*.lnk"
  On Error Resume Next
    Kill shortCutPath
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I cant figure out how I would loop through all shortcuts in the directory using the above loop.

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated
Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Access you could use the Dir() function. It would be something like this:

```
  Dim strLink As String

  strLink = Dir(shortCutPath & "*.lnk")
  Do Until Len(strLink)=0
    Kill strLink
    strLink = Dir()
  Loop
```

Dir() doesn't play well with network paths in all cases, though, so you might want to use the File System Object, instead. It's much more versatile and works better with networks. I use it only occasionally, so don't have the code at my fingertips, but have a look at it -- you might have no trouble figuring it out as the object model is pretty clearly designed.

Comment: Cheers for the advice @David-W-Fenton Had a look around at the file system object and came to a solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this may be good to someone.
To delete shortcuts by the shorcut target I used the following:

```
Public Sub deleteShortcutByTarget(targetFolderName As String)
Dim strDocPath As String
Dim strTarget As String
Dim obj As Object
Dim shortcut As Object
Dim objFso As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile  As Object

Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strDocPath = compName & recordDirShort

Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strDocPath)
Set objFile = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

 If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "lnk" Then
  Set shortcut = obj.CreateShortcut(objFile.Path)
  strTarget = shortcut.TargetPath
  shortcut.Save
   If strTarget = strDocPath & targetFolderName Then
     Kill objFile.Path
   End If
 End If

Next

Set obj = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFso = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set shortcut = Nothing

End Sub
```